# Python requests RequestsDependencyWarning which disappears after re-installing the same version of the library

Tags: python, docker, pip, centos, dockerfile

I'm building a python environment within a docker container using a Dockerfile. One of the levels is to pip install a requirements.txt file which includes the following libraries:

```
chardet==3.0.4
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.6
```

After the image has been built I create a container instance and run the following inside it:
`python -c "import requests"`
which gives the following output:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.6) or chardet (2.2.1) doesn't match a supported version! RequestsDependencyWarning)
```

Fair enough, however if I reinstall requests, `pip install --upgrade requests --force-reinstall`, and run the same python command above I don't receive the warning.

I can check the versions of each library again within the container and they're exactly the same as before:

```
chardet==3.0.4
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.6
```

So why would `requests` have been issuing the error before, and how can I ensure this warning doesn't come up within my Docker image without having a dangling re-install level in my Dockerfile?

I haven't found any adverse affects so far while using `requests` within my code while the warning is popping-up, however I'd rather it not be there since something is obviously triggering it.

I've found a number of posts/articles that suggest just sticking with re-installing `requests`, however I wouldn't want this redundant step within the Dockerfile unless it was the only way to resolve the warning.

Interestingly reinstalling `chardet` also removes the warning however reinstalling `urllib3` does not.

-- edit --
Dockerfile as requested:

```
FROM centos:7

# Install external yum repositories
RUN yum install -y \
        epel-release \
        https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
        && yum clean all

# Install required rpm dependencies
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
RUN yum install -y \
        systemd-python.x86_64 \
        git222 \
        gcc \
        python2-devel \
        openldap-devel \
        python-perf \
        python-linux-procfs \
        python-schedutils \
        policycoreutils-python \
        python-slip \
        python-slip-dbus \
        && yum clean all

# Install required pip dependencies
ADD requirements.txt /home/admin/container_files/
RUN pip install setuptools==30.1.0
RUN pip install -r /home/admin/container_files/requirements.txt

# Final update of packages
RUN yum update -y && yum clean all
```

Comment: I think that has to do with python and pip versions, you can use python base image to make sure that you have the correct versions of them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though base python images are debian based while I'm needing a centos7 base. Centos7 comes with python 2.7.5 + I've installed the latest (recommended?) version of pip that'd come from pip's own website. I'm hoping these two aren't incompatible!

Comment: you can use this https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-27-centos7 or whatever version you want

Comment: Ah ok I have tried this base image but it comes with a multitude of its own problems for my project! I've found far more success with the base centos7 image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the workaround will be to re-order the install in your file to:

```
chardet==3.0.4
urllib3==1.25.6
requests==2.22.0
```

now `python -c "import requests"` will work from the first time

and I suggest you to move :

```
RUN yum update -y && yum clean all
```

to second line , then that will be cached if you edit some of your later code.

Comment: thank you this has done it! Somehow I hadn't tried re-ordering the requirements.txt list like that..!? 
Also thanks for the docker tip - I've modified my Dockerfile accordingly :)